# How to use find to copy and remove directories?

Tags: shell, find

I am trying to find the files which are older than some days and i want to copy the files to the specific folder and to remove the files from the source directory in a single command.

```
find . -type d -mtime +600 -exec cp -rf '{}' destination folder  \; -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Error:

```
find: ./one: No such file or directory
find: ./two: No such file or directory
find: ./three: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Try using the `-delete` flag: http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 find . -type d -mtime -600 -exec cp -rf '{}' destination_folder \; -delete
```

Alternatively, you could even use

```
find . -type d -mtime -600 -print0 -exec cp -rf '{}' destination_folder \; | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: `delete` forces `find` to traverse in DFS, which is probably going to cause issues with the `cp -r`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you're doing `cp` and `rm`, rather than the much faster `mv`?

But, you can largely ignore that error, `find` pre-processes part of the tree, if you want to force it to ignore the removed subdirectories add `-prune` (you probably should quote `destination dir`)

```
find . -type d -mtime +600 -exec cp -rf '{}' 'destination folder' \; -exec rm -rf '{}' \; -prune
```

.

```
-prune True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it. If -depth is given,  false;  no  effect.
       Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```